# Remove one payment gateway if a coupon is applied

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to remove a specific payment gateway if at least 1 coupon is applied. I tried *"[Remove some payment gateways if any coupon code is applied in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52120053/remove-some-payment-gateways-if-any-coupon-code-is-applied-in-woocommerce/52121079#52121079)"* answer code with no results, *(the slug of the payment gateway to be removed is `'scalapay_gateway'`)*.

Any help?

Comment: The code works perfectly, so your problem can be due to a wrong payment ID slug.

Comment: Thank you for the edit and answer @LoicTheAztec , however the answer below (by Elman Huseynov) worked on the first try. Thank you both!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'unset_gatway_by_applied_coupons');

function unset_gatway_by_applied_coupons($available_gateways)
{

    $coupons = WC()->cart->applied_coupons;

    foreach ($coupons as $coupon) {

        if(isset($available_gateways['scalapay_gateway'])){
          unset($available_gateways['scalapay_gateway']);
        }

    }

    return $available_gateways;
}
```

Comment: Thank you vm, what if I want to remove the gateway for every coupon code?